# Numerically Solving ODE with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm stuck with applying `scipy.integrate.odeint` to the following very simple ODE:

```
y(t)/dt = y(t) + t^2 and y(0) = 0
```

The solution computed by SciPy is not correct (most likely b/c I confuse something here) - particularly the solution does not meet the initial condition.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# the definition of the ODE equation
def f(y,t): 
    return [t**2 + y[0]]

# computing the solution
ts = np.linspace(-3,3,1000)
res = scipy.integrate.odeint(f, [0], ts)

# the solution computed by WolframAlpha [1]
def y(t):
    return -t**2 - 2*t + 2*math.exp(t) - 2

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(ts, res[:,0])
ax1.text(0.5, 0.95,'SciPy solution', ha='center', va='top',
         transform = ax1.transAxes)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.plot(ts, np.vectorize(y)(ts))
ax1.text(0.5, 0.95,'WolframAlpha solution', ha='center', va='top',
         transform = ax1.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgfPz.png) : [WolframAlpha: "solve dy(t)/dt = t^2 + y(t), y(0) = 0"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dy%28t%29%2Fdt+%3D+t%5E2+%2B+y%28t%29%2C+y%280%29+%3D+0)

[image]

**Where's my bug?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scipy code solved the differential equation with initial condition `y(-3) = 0`, not `y(0) = 0`.  The `y0` argument of `odeint` is the value at the first time given in the `t` argument.

One way to solve this on the interval [-3, 3] with y(0) = 0 is to call `odeint` twice, as follows:

```
In [81]: from scipy.integrate import  odeint

In [82]: def f(y,t): 
   ....:         return [t**2 + y[0]]
   ....: 

In [83]: tneg = np.linspace(0, -3, 500)

In [84]: tpos = np.linspace(0, 3, 500)

In [85]: sol_neg = odeint(f, [0], tneg)

In [86]: sol_pos = odeint(f, [0], tpos)

In [87]: plot(tneg, sol_neg)
Out[87]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10f890d90>]

In [88]: plot(tpos, sol_pos)
Out[88]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x107a43cd0>]

In [89]: grid(True)
```

which creates
[image: plot of solution]

Comment: what would be the easiest way to solve for y(0)=0 but still compute for [-3,3]?

Comment: Maybe compute from 0 to 3 and afterwards from 0 to -3